# Authorize.net newly generated key not working in woo commerce authorize.net payment gateway

Tags: php, woocommerce, e-commerce, payment-gateway, authorize.net

Authorize.net newly generated key not working in woo commerce authorize.net payment gateway.

I have one old key of authorize.net. It works fine, I tested several times.

But when I generated new transaction key and signature key from authorize.net account and put it on WooCommerce authorize.net setting. Then placed order with authorize.net with card number , expiry date and cvp. It showed following error:

```
"Code: E00003, Message: The element 'getCustomerPaymentProfileRequest' in
 namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd' has invalid child
 element 'customerPaymentProfileId' in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.
 List of possible elements expected: 'clientId, refId, customerProfileId'
 in namespace 'AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd'.
 An error occurred, please try again or try an alternate form of payment.
```

Comment: You're calling the endpoint with new field `customerPaymentProfileId`, but the server uses old one with `customerProfileId`. You need to update your metadata

Comment: The v1 schema contains both attributes on line 3132: https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd

Answer (score 0):

An issue with your credentials would have triggered [E00007](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/responseCodes.html?code=E00007), the error you are getting suggest possibly *customerProfileId* is not being set, you may want to check the submitted raw request, and review Authorize.Net API reference for [getCustomerPaymentProfileRequest](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#customer-profiles-get-customer-payment-profile).